# Convert final appendix to a supplementary material section

Tags: labels, appendices, cleveref

I am writing a document where each chapter has an appendix. In addition to the appendices I would like to have a final supplementary files section where I list all the files that accompany the document each in their own section.

I am using both the `appendix` and `cleveref` packages.

Essentially when I refer to an appendix I would like the in-text reference to say "Appendix X" except when referring to the final appendix where it should say "Supplement X.X".

In addition since appendices are labeled alphabetically I would like to set the appendix counter forward to 19 so that the supplementary files section is section "S".

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[toc,page,titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[capitalise,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

TITLE 

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter 1}

Here is an idea (\cref{app:ch1}). The raw data is available in \cref{app:supp1}.

\chapter{Test Chapter 2}

Another idea.

\appendix
\chapter{Test Chapter 1}
\label{app:ch1}

\chapter{Test Chapter 2}
\label{app:ch2}

\crefalias{sectiom}{supp}

\chapter{Supplementary material}
\section{Supplementary material of chapter 1}
\label{app:supp1}
\section{Supplementary material of chapter 2}
\label{app:supp2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `appendices` environment you can control things a little more finely:

Table of contents:

[image: Table of contents]

Text reference:

[image: Text reference]

Supplementary material:

[image: Supplementary material]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[toc,page,titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[capitalise,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\crefname{supp}{Supplement}{Supplements}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  TITLE
\end{center}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter 1}

Here is an idea (\cref{app:ch1}).
The raw data is available in \cref{app:supp1}.

\chapter{Test Chapter 2}

Another idea.

\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Test Chapter 1}
\label{app:ch1}

\chapter{Test Chapter 2}
\label{app:ch2}
\end{appendices}

\appendixpageoff
\appendixtitleoff
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Supplementary material}
\begin{appendices}
  \setcounter{chapter}{19}
  \crefalias{section}{supp}
  \chapter*{Supplementary material}
  \section{Supplementary material of chapter 1}
  \label{app:supp1}
  \section{Supplementary material of chapter 2}
  \label{app:supp2}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

The ingredients are as follows:

1. Ordinary appendices in their `appendices` environment with options controlled by the option passed to the `appendix` package
2. Supplementary material in a separate `appendices` environment, where the extra page and heading are turned off, the toc name is adjusted, the chapter counter is set to `19` (corresponding to "S"), the chapter title is provide by `\chapter*` and the section counter is aliased to `supp`
3. A `\crefname` instruction to print references to the `supp` counter with the name `Supplement`

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below given

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[toc,page,titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[capitalise,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\appendix{\par
  \setcounter{chapter}{0}%
  \setcounter{section}{0}%
  \def\@chapapp{\appendixname}%
  \def\thechapter{\@Alph\c@chapter}}
  \makeatother

\begin{document}

TITLE

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter 1}

Here is an idea (\cref{app:ch1}). The raw data is available in \cref{app:supp1}.

\chapter{Test Chapter 2}

Another idea.

{
\appendix
\chapter{Test Chapter 1}
\label{app:ch1}

\chapter{Test Chapter 2}
\label{app:ch2}
}

\crefalias{sectiom}{supp}

\renewcommand\chaptername{Supplementary}
\def\thechapter{S}

\chapter*{Supplementary material}
\section{Supplementary material of chapter 1}
\label{app:supp1}
\section{Supplementary material of chapter 2}
\label{app:supp2}


\end{document}
```